# How to split this data into supplier and price and store it separately in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I actually passed a set of data from python to a variable in javascript
as following:

Javascript code:

```
var actresult = {'s01': ('supplier1', '50.70'), 's02': ('supplier2', 
'66.80'), 's03': ('supplier3', '42.20')};
```

My question is about how to split this data into supplier and price and store it separately in a two dimensional array.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @31piy I'm currently trying to design Line Chart using Google Chart by using JavaScript. Those data above will be put in JavaScript. I just need to find a way to split those data and put it into two dimensional array where one is supplier and the other one is price.

Comment: You have to provide the desired format and what have you done so far?

Comment: afaik `var actresult` is valid JS but not python, and this part `'s01': ('supplier1', '50.70')` is valid in both, JS and python but it means diferent things in the two languages. in JS `('supplier1', '50.70') === '50.70'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
actresult = {'s01': ('supplier1', '50.70'), 's02': ('supplier2', '66.80'), 's03': ('supplier3', '42.20')}


myarray = []
for supplier, price in actresult.values():
    myarray.append([supplier, price])

print(myarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in yourDict:
    yourList1.append( [ key , yourDict[key][0] ]
    yourList2.append( [ key , yourDict[key][1] ]
```

Comment: Code examples provide a good starting place, however please provide an explanation to this code to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
actresult = {'s01': ('supplier1', '50.70'), 's02': ('supplier2', 
'66.80'), 's03': ('supplier3', '42.20')};


supp=[]
price=[]
for key,value in actresult.items():
    supp.append(value[0])
    price.append(value[1])

print(supp)
print(price)
#pass to your javascript code like this:
a={"supp":supp,"price":price}
#for 2D array
a=[supp,price]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct JSON server responce?
I mean these round bracers `('supplier1', '50.70')`.

Maybe it reprecents data like an array `['supplier1', '50.70']`?

Then you could try to separate fields using Object.value to get an array of values and Array.map it to get data you need.

```
const suppliersIds = Object.keys(actresult);
const suppliers = Object.values(actresult).map(([supplier]) => supplier);
const prices = Object.values(actresult).map(([sup, price]) => price);
```

`.map(([sup, price]) =>` is es6 way to destruct array elements